# Eclipse RCP application - cant build project

Tags: eclipse, product, rcp

My Eclipse RCP project stopped running and i havent changed anything. I have two run configurations, one is .product and another one is application (both had run before problem occured).

When i try to run .product configuration, build is terminated without any log in console (i tried to run debugger but it is terminated somewhere inside native code).

When i try to run .application configuration, there is a lot of errors in console:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 2 2015-12-30 08:00:41.367
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in "org.eclipse.swtbot.eclipse.ui" was unable to instantiate class "org.eclipse.swtbot.eclipse.ui.preferences.PreferenceInitializer".
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.getExecutableExtension(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$56.run(Workbench.java:2812)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.swtbot.eclipse.ui.preferences.PreferenceInitializer.<init>(PreferenceInitializer.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
    ... 11 more
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.registry 4 1 2015-12-30 08:00:41.368
!MESSAGE Plug-in "org.eclipse.swtbot.eclipse.ui" was unable to instantiate class "org.eclipse.swtbot.eclipse.ui.preferences.PreferenceInitializer".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.swtbot.eclipse.ui.preferences.PreferenceInitializer.<init>(PreferenceInitializer.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.getExecutableExtension(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$56.run(Workbench.java:2812)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.registry 4 1 2015-12-30 08:00:41.368
!MESSAGE Plug-in "org.eclipse.swtbot.eclipse.ui" was unable to instantiate class "org.eclipse.swtbot.eclipse.ui.preferences.PreferenceInitializer".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.swtbot.eclipse.ui.preferences.PreferenceInitializer.<init>(PreferenceInitializer.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.getExecutableExtension(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$56.run(Workbench.java:2812)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2015-12-30 08:00:41.370
!MESSAGE Unhandled Exception

!ENTRY org.eclipse.swtbot.eclipse.ui 4 0 2015-12-30 08:00:41.371
!MESSAGE Unable to execute early startup code for an extension
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in "org.eclipse.swtbot.eclipse.ui" was unable to instantiate class "org.eclipse.swtbot.eclipse.ui.preferences.PreferenceInitializer".
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.getExecutableExtension(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$56.run(Workbench.java:2812)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.swtbot.eclipse.ui.preferences.PreferenceInitializer.<init>(PreferenceInitializer.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
    ... 11 more
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.registry 4 1 2015-12-30 08:00:41.371
!MESSAGE Plug-in "org.eclipse.swtbot.eclipse.ui" was unable to instantiate class "org.eclipse.swtbot.eclipse.ui.preferences.PreferenceInitializer".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.swtbot.eclipse.ui.preferences.PreferenceInitializer.<init>(PreferenceInitializer.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.getExecutableExtension(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$56.run(Workbench.java:2812)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 2 2015-12-30 08:00:41.373
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.monitoring.MonitoringStartup.earlyStartup(MonitoringStartup.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.runEarlyStartup(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$56.run(Workbench.java:2812)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2015-12-30 08:00:41.373
!MESSAGE Unhandled Exception

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.monitoring 4 0 2015-12-30 08:00:41.374
!MESSAGE Unable to execute early startup code for an extension
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.monitoring.MonitoringStartup.earlyStartup(MonitoringStartup.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.runEarlyStartup(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$56.run(Workbench.java:2812)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 2 2 2015-12-30 08:00:42.189
!MESSAGE Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.epp.internal.logging.aeri.ide.Startup$1
Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.epp.internal.logging.aeri.ide.Startup$1

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 2 2 2015-12-30 08:00:42.190
!MESSAGE Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.wizards.MarketplaceDropAdapter$1
Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.wizards.MarketplaceDropAdapter$1
```

The exception from first error log is thrown here (but it is not the LinkageError, just Exception):

```
try {
        result = classInstance.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throwException(NLS.bind(RegistryMessages.plugin_instantiateClassError, contributingBundle.getSymbolicName(), className), e);
    } catch (LinkageError e1) {
```

I tried to remove:
.metadata.plugins
.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench\workingsets.xml

but the problem still exists

EDIT: Problem is resolved. I started application with clear flag (Run Configuration->Main(bookmark)->Workspace Data (Area)->Clear (Flag) and errors disappeared)

Comment: It is the constructor of `org.eclipse.swtbot.eclipse.ui.preferences.PreferenceInitializer` which is getting a `NullPointerException`.  Possibly it is doing something that does not work in early startup code.

Comment: how to check/debug it?